# Constructor with interface arguments in Java Class Diagrams

Tags: java, interface, arguments, uml, diagram

I have a Interface in my project like,

```
public interface TraOp{
}
```

Now in class A I use this interface as argument in constructor like,

```
class A implements B{
   
   private long var1;
   A(TraOp obj){}
}
```

Can someone let me know how this will be presented in class diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UML:

- a class `A` that implements an interface `B` has a realization dependency.  This is represented like inheritance, but a dashed line as explained by [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244461/3723423).
- a class `A` that used `TrapOp`, for example as parameter in has a usage dependency, noted with the `«use»` keyword.

[image]

Comment: what does <<create>> signifies here ?

Comment: @AMS The `«create»` is a keyword to identify a constructor: “*A constructor is an operation having a single return result parameter of the type of the owning class, and marked with the standard stereotoe «create»*” (UML 2.5 specifications, page 193). In UML the constructor does not have to have the name of the class. Therefore to distinguish an ordinary operation that returns a result of the same class from the constructor that creates a new instance, this keyword is required. Many people use the convention of leading OOP languages to simply give the constructor the name of the class. (1/2)

Comment: @AMS Most readers will de facto understand this convention. But nowhere in the UML specs is this convention ever mentioned. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the class diagram like this.

[image: class diagram]